# What is difference between Java calendar vs Android calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-calendar, java-calendar

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to get the current date but the Android [`Calendar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/Calendar) class requires API 24. I need to support older device and the [`Time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time) class is deprecated since API 22.

The problem is how to get current date on API 23 and I solved it by using [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) which works on all versions. So what should I use, Android calendar or Java calendar?

Note that day, month and year are just integers when using the Android calendar.

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    day =android.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(android.icu.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = android.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(android.icu.util.Calendar.MONTH);
    year = android.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(android.icu.util.Calendar.YEAR);
}
else {
    day = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
    year = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

And when using only Java calendar there's no need to check the API version

```java
day = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
month = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
year = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## tl;dr

> So what should I use, Android calendar or Java calendar?

**Neither.**

Use the modern *java.time* classes. Available in all Android versions via Gradle Plugin 4.

```
LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )
```

## Avoid legacy classes

In Java, the terrible `java.util.Calendar` class (and related classes, `Date` etc.) was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Now available in Android 26 and later.

The *ThreeTen-Backport* library bring must of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7 using virtually identical API. That project is further adapted for Android <26 in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

I strongly recommend avoiding the legacy classes, instead using only the *java.time* classes. These modern classes are defined in JSR 310, and led by the same man who led the industry-leading *Joda-Time* library, Stephen Colebourne. So they have excellent design based on many years of experience. Using *ThreeTenABP* is well worth the bother of adding the library to your project.

For a date-only, year-month-day, without a time-of-day and without a time zone, use the `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 ) ;
```

Or use the handy `Month` enum for more readability.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: this require API 26 and my problem how to support old versions

Comment: @IslamAssem Reread my Answer more carefully looking for “Android” in bullets at the end.

Comment: Could you please explain in details why the legacy date-time classes are troublesome ?

Comment: @vhamon [*What's wrong with Java Date & Time API?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/642706). And those Answers there only cover *some* of the problems, there are more. One of those  problems is missing types, unable to represent important date-time concepts. I’ll add a graphic table here to show what is lacking.

Comment: May I suggest, mention of ThreeTenABP should be the footnote and desugaring should be front and center as the recommendation. It doesn't make sense to use ThreeTenABP in new projects when desugaring is available. This answer reads like it is strongly recommending ThreeTenABP and it would be easy to read it and miss the comment about desugaring.